# Правильно ли будет заменить все простые значения константами, в большом пректе?

Tags: c++

К примеру, вместо `0` везде писать `MyConst0` и т.д.
Правильно в плане производительности и стабильности.

```
        Matrix4 r0, r1, r2, r3;
        f32 a, det, invDet;
        f32* mat = reinterpret_cast<f32 *>(this);

        det = mat[0*4+0] * mat[1*4+1] - mat[0*4+1] * mat[1*4+0];
        if ( std::abs( det ) < 1e-14 ) {
            return false;
        }
        v4f dd;

        invDet = 1.0f / det;

        r0[0][0] =   mat[1*4+1] * invDet;
        r0[0][1] = - mat[0*4+1] * invDet;
        r0[1][0] = - mat[1*4+0] * invDet;
        r0[1][1] =   mat[0*4+0] * invDet;
        r1[0][0] = r0[0][0] * mat[0*4+2] + r0[0][1] * mat[1*4+2];
        r1[0][1] = r0[0][0] * mat[0*4+3] + r0[0][1] * mat[1*4+3];
        r1[1][0] = r0[1][0] * mat[0*4+2] + r0[1][1] * mat[1*4+2];
        r1[1][1] = r0[1][0] * mat[0*4+3] + r0[1][1] * mat[1*4+3];
        r2[0][0] = mat[2*4+0] * r1[0][0] + mat[2*4+1] * r1[1][0];
        r2[0][1] = mat[2*4+0] * r1[0][1] + mat[2*4+1] * r1[1][1];
        r2[1][0] = mat[3*4+0] * r1[0][0] + mat[3*4+1] * r1[1][0];
        r2[1][1] = mat[3*4+0] * r1[0][1] + mat[3*4+1] * r1[1][1];
        r3[0][0] = r2[0][0] - mat[2*4+2];
        r3[0][1] = r2[0][1] - mat[2*4+3];
        r3[1][0] = r2[1][0] - mat[3*4+2];
        r3[1][1] = r2[1][1] - mat[3*4+3];

        det = r3[0][0] * r3[1][1] - r3[0][1] * r3[1][0];
        if ( std::abs( det ) < 1e-14 ) {
            return false;
        }

        invDet = 1.0f / det;

        a = r3[0][0];
        r3[0][0] =   r3[1][1] * invDet;
        r3[0][1] = - r3[0][1] * invDet;
        r3[1][0] = - r3[1][0] * invDet;
        r3[1][1] =   a * invDet;
        r2[0][0] = mat[2*4+0] * r0[0][0] + mat[2*4+1] * r0[1][0];
        r2[0][1] = mat[2*4+0] * r0[0][1] + mat[2*4+1] * r0[1][1];
        r2[1][0] = mat[3*4+0] * r0[0][0] + mat[3*4+1] * r0[1][0];
        r2[1][1] = mat[3*4+0] * r0[0][1] + mat[3*4+1] * r0[1][1];
        mat[2*4+0] = r3[0][0] * r2[0][0] + r3[0][1] * r2[1][0];
        mat[2*4+1] = r3[0][0] * r2[0][1] + r3[0][1] * r2[1][1];
        mat[3*4+0] = r3[1][0] * r2[0][0] + r3[1][1] * r2[1][0];
        mat[3*4+1] = r3[1][0] * r2[0][1] + r3[1][1] * r2[1][1];
        mat[0*4+0] = r0[0][0] - r1[0][0] * mat[2*4+0] - r1[0][1] * mat[3*4+0];
        mat[0*4+1] = r0[0][1] - r1[0][0] * mat[2*4+1] - r1[0][1] * mat[3*4+1];
        mat[1*4+0] = r0[1][0] - r1[1][0] * mat[2*4+0] - r1[1][1] * mat[3*4+0];
        mat[1*4+1] = r0[1][1] - r1[1][0] * mat[2*4+1] - r1[1][1] * mat[3*4+1];
        mat[0*4+2] = r1[0][0] * r3[0][0] + r1[0][1] * r3[1][0];
        mat[0*4+3] = r1[0][0] * r3[0][1] + r1[0][1] * r3[1][1];
        mat[1*4+2] = r1[1][0] * r3[0][0] + r1[1][1] * r3[1][0];
        mat[1*4+3] = r1[1][0] * r3[0][1] + r1[1][1] * r3[1][1];
        mat[2*4+2] = -r3[0][0];
        mat[2*4+3] = -r3[0][1];
        mat[3*4+2] = -r3[1][0];
        mat[3*4+3] = -r3[1][1];
```

Comment: Зависит от того что Вы вкладываете в понятие `правильно`. 

Замена чисел на константы обычно делается чтобы избежать магических чисел и улучшить читаемость кода. В вашем случае с константами читаемость вряд-ли улучшится

Comment: А, ну так ничего же не изменится. Что так что так константы

Comment: @vegorov дополнил вопрос

Comment: В вашем случае нужна инлайн функция, чтобы не было описок:  `f32 & Mat(size_t x , size_t y){return mat[y*4+x];}` так цифра 4 спрячется

Comment: Для конкретно этого кусочка кода  литералы предпочтительней в плане наглядности и читабельности, в остальном нет никакой разницы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заводить именованную константу для какого-либо значения имеет смысл лишь в том случае, если допускается вариант в дальнейшем изменять это значение. Таким образом это позволит поменять его в одном месте, где определяется величина, а все остальные места уже подхватятся автоматически.

Если же такой ситуации не наблюдается, т.е. используются вычисления для какого-то одного фиксированного случая, то замена числовых литералов на константы не даст никакого выигрыша, а может быть даже и ухудшить читабельность.

Например, в вашем случае, можно было бы вынести константу `const eps = 1e-14;`, а индексы оставить как есть.

Заводить же вместо `0` переменную `MyConst0` не имеет вообще никакого смысла. Имя должно отражать в первую очередь суть, а не значение, которое хранится внутри. Будет странно потом изменить значение на, скажем, `1` и оставить при этом старое имя.

Comment: *"Заводить именованную константу для какого-либо значения имеет смысл лишь в том случае, если допускается вариант в дальнейшем изменять это значение."* - я с этим категорически не согласен. Вот например число пи явно изменяться не будет, но копипастить его вместо использования именованной константы было бы трешово.

Comment: @VTT согласен, здесь немного погорячился.

Answer (score 2):

Да, всегда следует использовать именованные константы вместо литералов для объявления особых значений. Это позволит избежать многих ошибок копирования при использовании этих значений, упростит вызов некоторых методов, улучшит читабельность и поддерживаемость кода.

Однако ключевое слово здесь - *особых*. Например в вашем случае нет никакого смысла делать 0, 1, 2, 3, и т.п. константами, так как эти значения не несут в себе никакого особого смысла. Это просто элементы ряда положительных чисел. Названия вроде `MyConst0` явно говорят о том, что значения ничем не выделяются и вы не получите никаких из перечисленных выше выгод, а сами эти значения у вас накопипасчены просто из-за отсутствия надлежащих методов (для подсчета определителя, для получения размеров матрицы, для итерации / копирования матрицы и т.п.).

Контрпример: константа вроде `MyConst0` вполне могла бы иметь смысл если бы ее тип был классом-оберткой. Тогда с ее помощью было бы удобно инициализировать переменные этого класса с выводом типа или было бы проще вызывать перегруженные функции.